# Docker volume mounting empty

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm making an image to host a PHP application. I'm using `COPY` to populate `/var/www/html` with the app files and creating a `VOLUME /var/www/html` to mount the dir on the host and edit files like config.

But:

1. When I mount the volume in docker-compose.yml, the directory is empty.
2. When I omit the "volume" entry in the docker-compose.yml and connect with the container shell, the directory /var/www/html is filled.

I already read tons of examples and documentation but, sincerely, don't know what is wrong.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache-buster
LABEL description="OCOMON 3.2 Frontend (noDB)"
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www/html/ocomon

COPY ./ocomon .

VOLUME /var/www/html/ocomon
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    ocomon:
        image: ocomon:3.2
        container_name: ocomon
        volumes:
            - ./volumes/ocomon/ocomon:/var/www/ocomon
        ports:
            - 4682:80
```

Comment: You're mounting `/var/www/ocomon`, while your workdir is `/var/www/html/ocomon`. Is that right? I think you may have not written the correct path.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo when I was editing the post. I had it tested with the right paths.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your host's directory is `${PWD}/www/html`, then you need only provide the `volumes` value in `docker-compose.yml` and it should be:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache-buster
LABEL description="OCOMON 3.2 Frontend (noDB)"
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www/html/ocomon

COPY ./www/html/ocomon .
```

and:
`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  ocomon:
    image: ocomon:3.2
    container_name: ocomon
    volumes:
    - ${PWD}/www/html:/var/www/html
    ports:
    - 4682:80
```

### Explanation

- Dockerfile `VOLUMES` creates a volume in the image. By following `WORKDIR` (which always create if the path does not exist), with `VOLUME`, you overwrite whatever was either in (or created by `WORKDIR`). **NOTE** this is done during image **build**.
- Docker Compose `volumes` mounts a directory from the host into the image. The syntax is `volumes: - ${HOST_PATH}:${IMAGE_PATH}`. **NOTE** this is done during image **run**.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this changes latter and post the results. For now, I had do create the volume at the docker-compose.yml and copy the source code after the container starts running.